# Divinity Original Sin EE - Can the elemental forge be used for crafting?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I've reached the **elemental forge** and broken Boreas's staff. I've also read that you can do something with weresheep wool.

But is there anything else we can do with the elemental forge ? Like improving weapons or shields ? I can't seem to find anything online.

I've already checked following sources:

- [Crafting Page on Wikia](http://divinity.wikia.com/wiki/Crafting_(Divinity:_Original_Sin))
- [Crafting Guide on Steam Forums](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=546088017)
- [Official game recipes](http://www.divinityoriginalsin.com/usergen/ivar_recipes.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there's only one thing you can craft with Elemental Forge, apart from that quest you mentionned:

> Weresheep Wool + Elemental Forge = Weresheep Armor

Source: [Crafting Guide](http://tamarasaurus.github.io/divinity-crafting/) and [tihie.com](https://www.tihie.com/divinity-original-sin-ee/crafting-all-you-need-to-know)

Comment: Ya thanks I'm aware of that one, I just felt that since it's called a forge , it should have had some more crafting ..

Comment: apparently no. But a "no" still answers your question ^^'